# disable self keypress detection in pynput lib (python 3 in linux)

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, python-2.7

I want write a program when I hit the 'space' key it hit 'space' key again. (duble space)

I wrote some code with "pynput", but when the program hits the space key, it thinks that I hit space again and it falls into an infinite loop that hits space.

what sould i do?

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller,Listener
k = Controller()


def on_release(key):
    print(key)
    if key == Key.space:
        k.press(Key.space)
        k.release(Key.space)


# Collect events until released
with Listener(on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

i use linux mint, i think in windows i haven't this problem

this is what happend to me: [space press loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJPSL.gif)

Answer (score 0):

added a delay of 300ms, should work

def on_release(key):
print(key)
if key == Key.space:
time.sleep(0.3)
k.press(Key.space)
k.release(Key.space)

Comment: the xev tool will help you solve this (https://www.commandlinux.com/man-page/man1/xev.1.html)